# Set Pixel Dimensions in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab

I am pretty new to MatLab. I simply want to display an image for viewing, the image is 1024 x 1024 array. I have been using imagesc to display the image with a line of code such as this:

`imagesc(xRange, yRange, imageData, [Min Max]);`

However my image dimensions are not equal. For example, my image width is 10mm but in height it is 300mm, so I want it to appear reflecting this, so in this case I would expect it to appear very narrow but tall because the height is so much greater than the width. Instead it displays as a square which does not reflect the true dimensions.

I have looked at some MatLab functions but have not been successful in finding the correct one to do this. Does anybody know how i can set it so each pixel, point in the image is displayed reflecting its true dimensions? Thanks!

Comment: So you have rectangular pixels with a dimension of 1x30?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`daspect`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/daspect.html)

```
imagesc( imageData ); 
daspect([ 1 30 ] );
```

Answer (score 1):

Set your x and y ranges in terms of the desired image dimensions, and set the axes to be equal:

```
imagesc(xRange, yRange, imageData, [Min Max]);
axis equal tight
```